# Firebase analytics - Unity - time spent on a level

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

is there any possibility to get exact time spent on a certain level in a game via firebase analytics? Thank you so much

I tried to use logEvents.

Comment: Yes, there is. But you need to provide us more details, so we can help. You tried LogEvents and what exactly happened? They weren't logged to a console? They were, but not in the right form?

Comment: Yes, when you don't give more details you often don't get answers. Or you get long universal answers if you're lucky enough.  Consider adding more context and examples of your attempts to the question.

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do so would be measuring the time on the level within your codebase, then have a very dedicated event for level completion, in which you would pass the time spent on the level.

Let's get to details. I will use Kotlin as an example, but it should be obvious what I'm doing here and you can see more language examples [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android#kotlin%20ktx).

```
firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("user_id", userId)
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("level_completed") {
    param("name", levelName)
    param("difficulty", difficulty)
    param("subscription_status", subscriptionStatus)
    param("minutes", minutesSpentOnLevel)
    param("score", score)
}
```

Now see how I have a bunch of parameters with the event? These parameters are important since they will allow you to conduct a more thorough and robust analysis later on, answer more questions. Like, Hey, what is the most difficult level? Do people still have troubles on it when the game difficulty is lower? How many times has this level been rage-quit or lost (for that you'd likely need a `level_started` event). What about our paid players, are they having similar troubles on this level as well? How many people have ragequit the game on this level and never played again? That would likely be easier answer with sql at this point, taking the latest value of the level name for the `level_started`, grouped by the user_id. Or, you could also have levelName as a UserProperty as well as the EventProperty, then it would be somewhat trivial to answer in the default analytics interface.

Note that you're limited in the number of event parameters you can send per event. The total number of unique parameter names is limited too. As well as the number of unique event names you're allowed to have. In our case, the event name would be `level_completed`. See the limits [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9237506?hl=en).

Because of those limitations, it's important to name your event properties in somewhat generic way so that you would be able to efficiently reuse them elsewhere. For this reason, I named `minutes` and not something like `minutes_spent_on_the_level`. You could then reuse this property to send the minutes the player spent actively playing, minutes the player spent idling, minutes the player spent on any info page, minutes they spent choosing their upgrades, etc. Same idea about having `name` property rather than `level_name`. Could as well be `id`.

You need to carefully and thoughtfully stuff your event with event properties. I normally have a wrapper around the firebase sdk, in which I would enrich events with dimensions that I always want to be there, like the `user_id` or `subscription_status` to not have to add them manually every time I send an event. I also usually have some more adequate logging there Firebase Analytics default logging is completely awful. I also have some sanitizing there, lowercasing all values unless I'm passing something case-sensitive like base64 values, making sure I don't have double spaces (so replacing `\s+` with " " (space)), maybe also adding the user's local timestamp as another parameter. The latter is very helpful to indicate time-cheating users, especially if your game is an idler.

Good. We're halfway there :) Bear with me.

Now You need to go to firebase and register your eps (event parameters) into cds (custom dimensions and metrics). If you don't register your eps, they won't be counted towards the global cd limit count (it's about 50 custom dimensions and 50 custom metrics). You register the cds in the Custom Definitions section of FB.

Now you need to know whether this is a dimension or a metric, as well as the scope of your dimension. It's much easier than it sounds. The rule of thumb is: if you want to be able to run mathematical aggregation functions on your dimension, then it's a metric. Otherwise - it's a dimension. So:

```
    firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("user_id", userId) <-- dimension
    param("name", levelName) <-- dimension
    param("difficulty", difficulty)  <-- dimension (or can be a metric, depends)
    param("subscription_status", subscriptionStatus) <-- dimension (can be a metric too, but even less likely)
    param("minutes", minutesSpentOnLevel)  <-- metric
    param("score", score)  <-- metric
```

Now another important thing to understand is the scope. Because Firebase and GA4 are still, essentially just <s>in Beta</s> being actively worked on, you only have user or hit scope for the dimensions and only hit for the metrics. The scope basically just indicates how the value persists. In my example, we only need the user_id as a user-scoped cd. Because user_id is the user-level dimension, it is set separately form the logEvent function. Although I suspect you can do it there too. Haven't tried tho.

Now, we're almost there.

Finally, you don't want to use Firebase to look at your data. It's horrible at data presentation. It's good at debugging though. Cuz that's what it was intended for initially. Because of how horrible it is, it's always advised to [link it to GA4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en). Now GA4 will allow you to look at the Firebase values much more efficiently. Note that you will likely need to re-register your custom dimensions from Firebase in GA4. Because GA4 is capable of getting multiple data streams, of which firebase would be just one data source. But [GA4's CDs limits](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267744?hl=en) are very close to Firebase's. Ok, let's be frank. GA4's data model is almost exactly copied from that of Firebase's. But GA4 has a much better analytics capabilities.

Good, you've moved to GA4. Now, GA4 is a very raw not-officially-beta product as well as Firebase Analytics. Because of that, it's advised to first change your [data retention](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7667196?hl=en) to 12 months and only use the explorer for analysis, pretty much ignoring the pre-generated reports. They are just not very reliable at this point.

Finally, you may find it easier to just use SQL to get your analysis done. For that, you can easily copy your data from GA4 to a sandbox instance of BQ. It's very [easy](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) to do.This is the best, most reliable known method of using GA4 at this moment. I mean, advanced analysts do the export into BQ, then ETL the data from BQ into a proper storage like Snowflake or even s3, or Aurora, or whatever you prefer and then on top of that, use a proper BI tool like Looker, PowerBI, Tableau, etc. A lot of people just stay in BQ though, it's fine. Lots of BI tools have BQ connectors, it's just BQ gets expensive quickly if you do a lot of analysis.

Whew, I hope you'll enjoy analyzing your game's data. Data-driven decisions rock in games. Well... They rock everywhere, to be honest.